# Extract words/texts after a group of phrases in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I'm trying to write a function to extract words that come before or after a group of phrases.

Extracting words that come after a single phrase, for example, `item` in a string variable called `x`, I had luck with the below code:

```
str_extract(x, pattern="(?<=item).*?(?=,)")
```

How do I pass on a list of phrases to look for onto a regex? For example, I want to create a list of phrases, called `keywords` and extract a group of words that come after these phrases. How do I tell regex `keywords` is a list, not a text?

```
keywords <- c("item", 
              "date",
              "size",
              "length")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pattern` must look like

```r
paste0("(?<=", paste(keywords, collapse="|"),").*?(?=,)")
paste0("(?<=", paste(keywords, collapse="|"),")[^,]*")
```

The first pattern will look like `(?<=item|date|size|length).*?(?=,)`. This matches a location that is immediately preceded with `item`, `date`, `size` or `length`, then consumes any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of a comma without consuming it (as `(?=,)` is a positive lookahead).

The second regex will look like `(?<=item|date|size|length)[^,]*`, and will match similarly as above pattern. Note the difference though: `[^,]*` matches any zero or more chars other than a comma, so 1) it will match even if there is no comma later, and 2) it will match any chars including line break chars.